# Bind a value from code behind to datatemplate control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to wpf, I created a listbox it will create a dynamic listitems,Here I used datetemplate which contains two controls that is two textblocks, one textblocks contains binding a values form combobox(which is string datatype),The other one is, bind a value from code bind.

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding obj}"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  x:Name="lstbxindex" SelectionMode="Extended" Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="201" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="80,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282" Background="#555555" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
                <TextBlock Height="40px" Width="80px" Text="{Binding roundedhourvalue, FontSize="24" Background="#555555"  Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="items"  Text="{Binding}" Margin="35,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C# (Roundedhour.cs)

```
public class Roundedhour
{
    public string hourvalue { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return string.Format("{0}", hourvalue);
    }
}
```

In this class create a property for hourvalue. For this class I created a object in codebehind file which I mentioned below.create a object and assign a value for hourvalue variable.

C# (Code Behind)

```
{
    if (dispatcherTimer1.Interval == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
    {
        //lstbxindex.Items.Add(lstbxindex.SelectedItem.ToString());

        string hrvalue = Convert.ToString(hrvalueinitially);  

        obj = new Roundedhour();
        obj.hourvalue = Convert.ToString(hrvalueinitially);

        string roundedhourvalue =obj.hourvalue;

        this.DataContext = this;


        //lblprojectAhr.Content = string.Join(",", hrvalueinitially + "" + "hr");
    }
}
```

Here, I created a object for Rounderhour class.Assign values to that property hour value. But I cannot be bind a value from codebind to XAML page.

Comment: Your `DataContext` needs to have a `public` property containing a `{ get; } (getter)` to fetch the value from your `Binding`. Also note that the property in `Roundedhour` is called `hourvalue` not `roundedhourvalue`. **When having binding issues always check your `Output`-Window in VisualStudio.** -  there you will see what is missing where...

Answer (score 1):

Your `ItemsSource` should be of an `CollectionType`.

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding obj}"
```

**You should also start to give your variables and properties meaningful names. That makes it easier to read your code later o**n.

The second Problem is in your `Binding` itself.

You are binding like this: `Text="{Binding roundedhourvalue}`

**So WPF is expecting a property `roundedhourvalue` on `obj`**.

**But as shown in your `CodeBehind` there is only `obj.hourvalue`.**

So change your Binding to `Text="{Binding hourvalue}`

**Check your `Output-Window` for details.**

**NOTE:**

```
string roundedhourvalue = obj.hourvalue;
```

has no `getter` and is not accsessible since its `private`.

**NOTE**: You either use a `Binding` **OR** your set the ItemsSource in CodeBehind.

---

Try it like this:

Just remove all the formatting and stuff:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RoundedHours}" x:Name="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding hourvalue}"></TextBlock>                   
            </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And change your code-behind to this:

```
    private void UpdateDataContext(object hrvalueinitially)
    {
        List<Roundedhour> hours = new List<Roundedhour>();
        hours.Add(new Roundedhour()
        {
            hourvalue = hrvalueinitially.ToString()
        });

        //Set the ItemsSource in code: => remove your ItemsSource Binding from XAML
        listBox.ItemsSource = hours;
    }
```

OR your can use an 'MVVM' approach:

```
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //IMPLEMENT INotifyPropertyChanged HERE PLS

        public ObservableCollection<RoundedHour> Collection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RoundedHour>();

        private void AddToCollection(object hrvalueinitially)
        {
            Collection.Add(new RoundedHour()
            {
                hourvalue = hrvalueinitially.ToString()
            });
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }

        //Make sure to set your Windows DataContext to an Instance of this Class
    }
```

Comment: I changed the  Text={Binding hourvalue} but the values not binding in to the label.

Comment: You should read about
  [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'obj' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-2067273858)'. BindingExpression:Path=obj; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-2067273858); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Answer (score -1):

Assign XAML object's "ItemsSource" property with your binding variable.

Also it's totally wrong binding object's itself into object's property like

```
this.DataTemplate = this;
```

Use:

```
List<yourobject> bindingObjectList = new List<yourobject>();
// insert your objects into the list
this.ItemsSource = bindingObjectList;
```

Here you can find an example:

[Grid & Pivot Binding Example for multiple DataTemplates](https://github.com/kdrlzmlr/Flickra/tree/master/App5/App5.WindowsPhone)

Comment: this.ItemsSource = obj; get the values in this.ItemsSource but the value not binded to the label

Comment: You use "Listbox" and it has ItemsSource property which must be assigned on codebehind and this could not be completed within your code sample: this.DataContext = this; You need to assign itemssource a Collection like (List, Ienumerable etc). So you didn't bind anything yet to your view.